Disabling fusing attention in ViT models in PyTorch
I am inspecting different vision transformer models on PyTorch and I am trying to understand their differences. My models can be seen in the following code:
retrained_vit_weights = torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights.DEFAULT # requires torchvision >= 0.13, "DEFAULT" means best available
pretrained_vit_1 = torchvision.models.vit_b_16(weights=retrained_vit_weights).to(device)

pretrained_vit_2 = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/deit:main', 'deit_tiny_patch16_224', pretrained=True).to(device)

for block in pretrained_vit_2.blocks:
        block.attn.fused_attn = False

This code loads two different ViT models and disables the fused_attn variable for the second model. The models are a bit different, so I am trying to understand what exactly this code (block.attn.fused_attn = False) does and how can I apply it (or if its necessary to) in the first model.
Edit: The idea is that I would like to run the model in an image and return the attention maps and the gradient up to a specific layer (dropout after the self-attention). In the same way as it is explained here. Initially, I tried to use the facebookresearch deit_tiny_patch16_224 model, and then I am commenting out the following code lines:
for block in pretrained_vit_2.blocks:
        block.attn.fused_attn = False

When I commend out this code it results in empty list of attention maps (for each of the ViT layer) and gradient (the code uses a hook for attn_drop module). I am experiencing the same behavior for the ViT_B_16_Weights for which I am not sure how to disable the fused_attn and by default the gradient for the dropout  layer returns an empty list (while the attention maps are not empty in this case).
Any idea why this holds? Why when I comment this parameter the result is empty gradient/maps?
Secondly, how can I do the same for the ViT_B_16_Weights (that is loaded from torchvision)?
In the first model indeed there its composed of blocks that contains variable attn and the boolean variable fused_attn.
The second model composed of stacked Encoder layers pretrained_vit.encoder.layers each of them contain a Boolean add_zero_attention and I could not find nowhere fused_attn or something similar. It seems that in the second model by default it uses this attribute: scaled_dot_product_attention
Edit2:
Digging a bit into the implementation for attention in both models, for the case of the ViT_B_16_Weights I have noticed that there is the following comment in the self.attention implementation:
``nn.MultiHeadAttention`` will use the optimized implementations of
``scaled_dot_product_attention()`` when possible.

It feels that by default this model sets this variable to True. However, not sure how to disable and replace that in the code for the second model. Is there a way to disable scaled_dot_product_attention in the same way as the other model?
Edit 3:: After inspecting more about the ViT_B_16_Weights I could find in the vision_transformer.py a call to activation.py that in turns call the functional.py, there is some code with an if-else that relates to scaled_dot_product_attention. However, I am not sure how to activate if else statement for this model in the same way with the deit_tiny_patch16_224. Not even sure why the different calculations leads to different gradient/attention. Also, what it means to deactivate this variable when pretraining is set to false? Isn't that a bit weird?

You may want to refer to this.

@Ivan thanks for pointing out this! Not sure how to apply for the first model though! The model does not contain blocks in the same way like the second model.

The fused_attn flag is used by the timm library to select how attention is computed.
Standard attention computes attention values with multiple discrete operations (matmul, softmax, dropout, matmul).
Fused attention uses a single cuda kernel to apply all those operations. Fused attention is generally faster, but may require additional libraries or be less flexible in terms of inputs, dtypes, etc.
Pytorch has several different backends for fused attention docs

What it means when you disable that though? And how this can be done for the second model?
